# Syntax to process array from a POST, android?

Tags: php, android, http, http-post, basicnamevaluepair

I am passing an array to http post from my android app to php server as follows:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image[]", encodedImage));
```

Now I want all the values on image array, in my php code. How to achieve that?

How to write code for this?- I wanted to loop over this array and insert each image from image[] in php.

when I am trying to do

```
if(isset( $_POST['image'] )){
$images = array($_POST['image']);
  while($row = $images){
  //insert into table
  }
}
```

But this is not helping

This if condition for isset is failing.

Comment: If you're passing through http post, everything you need is inside `$_POST`.

Comment: Show us some PHP code!

Comment: Based on your edit, first you code it like `<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);`, then you save it like `server.php`, then you make sure your android app is pointing its post request to it, then you open it in a browser and then you'll see it. If a beautiful array is printed on the screen, you've made it. Now all you have to do is manipulate the `$_POST` superglobal to fit your needs.

Comment: when I am trying to do

if(isset( $_POST['images'] )){
       $images = array($_POST['images']);
while($row = $images){
//insert into table
}
}

But this is not helping

Answer (score 0):

Try this: if this works

```
if(isset($_POST['images'])){
  $images[] = $_POST['images'];

while($row = $images){
  //your query here
}
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($_POST['images'])`?

Comment: actually the if check itself is failing.

Comment: I am hitting the server with a mobile app. How to print this?